# Boot without password, but still have encrypted partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption

I'm trying to set up a server with encrypted (and non-encrypted) partitions, but would prefer not to need physical access to reboot it (it being a server and all). Is there a way to set up the encrypted partition so that it does not prevent the machine from booting into an SSH-able state (or require an encrypted swap which also needs to be unlocked with physical access at boot?)

It would be fine if it needs to be manually mounted after login, as long as I can safely do a `sudo reboot` without having to plug a monitor and keyboard in afterwards.

Ubuntu is being reinstalled anyway, so solutions that require making a new partition table are fine.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you ensure that non of the data on the encrypted partition is needed to enable a system boot you could just remove the reference to it from `/etc/crypttab` to stop it from being auto-mounted at boot. Alternatively you could leave the reference in place but add the `noauto` option.

As for the swap the easiest solution here is just to have it be encrypted using a random key each boot seeing as data on swap need not persist between reboots anyway this is perfectly fine you can use an entry like this in `crypttab` to do so:

```
sda6_crypt /dev/sda6 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,swap,discard
```

Replacing the `sda6` with your physical swap partition.